# Python automatic script to convert EML file in Hebrew to PDF

Tags: python, pdf, automation, eml

Anyone have any suggestions on how to automate this problem using Thunderbird. I have an EML file that contains Hebrew and every conversion tool does not properly convert the Hebrew text correctly( it moves the sentence to be read left to right) except for Thunderbird. I have been looking at modules for Python such as autokey and dogtail but could use some advice on how to tackle this problem. If I open up the EML file with thunderbird and go to print I can save the file as pdf. I would like to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

would use the last-in-first-out **(LIFO method)**. with a list.
In this way, you can enter the letters from left to right and you will consult them from right to left.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).